# MDX query problem (count measure over specific time range)

Tags: mdx, ssas

I have a very simple cube with buying transactions details.
dimentions:
1. Time dimension with two hierarchies:
 a. full date hierarchy: Year > Month > Day of Month
 b. day of week hierarchy: DayOfWeek > Day of Month

2. Store dimention with single member:
   a. store id

The face table contains store id and time for each transaction.

The query goal is to return the count measure on transactions on selected stores in a specific time range arranged by day of week member.
For example: the results for the input store ids (111,222,444) and time range(5/1/10 - 6/1/10) are attached. 
[image: simple results]

The query I`ve built:

`SELECT

[DATETIME_DIM].[Hierarchy].[Day Of Week] * [Measures].[Count] 
ON columns,

{

    {[STORE_DIM].[STORE ID].[111], [STORE_DIM].[STORE ID].[222], [STORE_DIM].[STORE ID].[444]}

} on rows

FROM [MY_CUBE]

where [DATETIME_DIM].[2010].[May].[1] : [DATETIME_DIM].[2010].[June].[1]`

The problem with my query is that it returns the count of transactions on the entire fact table and not specific on the time range I`ve asked.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try specifying one of the hierarchies. It seems like you have a hirarchy restriction in the columns clause, but not in the restriction clause.